# Any action with `apt` causes errors with `initramfs-tools`

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

**Ubuntu 22.04** 
Example:

`sudo apt-get auto-remove`

Returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libplymouth5
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 429 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 270459 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libplymouth5:amd64 (0.9.5+git20211018-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched the forum for a solution, that nothing helps. Tried the following:

```
$ sudo apt remove initramfs-tools
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt install initramfs-tools
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt autoclean
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt -f install
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

also:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc
```

Please help me :( 
I can't update ubuntu to 20.10, neither can I update any package.

Comment: Move the file into your home and try again.

Comment: What was the exact error message of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?